# JS, JQuery. Событие изменения координат и размеров элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

К примеру элемент, при клике по нему(или по таймеру, или еще как-то) меняет свое положение(координаты). Или изменяет свои размеры.

Как можно это отследить?

Comment: что вы подразумеваеет под "как отследить" ??

Comment: находим элемент по идентификатору/классу/имени и получаем его данные

Comment: @ampawd, я имею в виду событие. Т.е. когда он начинает движение или изменение размеры. Как, к примеру, mouseup.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Не ясно, когда именно нужно получать его данные. Т.е. он может начинать движение отложено, или после каких-нибудь других событий

Comment: @ssfn ну повесьте функцию отслеживания на setInterval. Эта функция будет проверять текущие координаты элемента относительно предыдущих. Если не равны - значит движется  и значит вы предпринимаете какие-то действия

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну так это понятно. Хотелось бы обработчик.. если есть что-то подобное